# Why is $\alpha = x^2dx^1 - x^1dx^2$ not a differential of a function?

Tags: differential-forms

Why is $\alpha = x^2dx^1 - x^1dx^2$ not a differential of a function?

I know that a $df$ can be expressed:

$$ df= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i$$

And I assumed that $\alpha$ is the differential of a function and get a necessary condition $f=0$

($f_{x^1}=x^2$ etc).

Does this show that $\alpha$ is not a differential of a function? If so can someone please try to tell me why? Thanks

Comment: Since $d\alpha\neq0$, $\alpha$ is not exact.

Comment: Hi In my course we have not come across the term exact, is there an alternative approach? Thank you

Comment: Well, the crossed derivatives are different.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but I don't even know what that means either :(

Comment: Since you have not told us what you *do* know, it is like shooting in the dark...

Comment: I'm guessing to say if $\alpha$ is differential of a function then $d \alpha$=0 from what you have said (maybe not), if so what can I type in to google to see why this is the case? If you know

Comment: The reason is simply that crossed derivatives of a function are equal.

Comment: Mariano is referring to the equality of mixed partial derivatives (sometimes terminology is different in different languages) :) If $f$ is continuously twice-differentiable, then $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^1\partial x^2} = \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2\partial x^1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

We have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}=x^2
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^2}=-x^1
$$
so:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^1\partial x^2}\ne \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2\partial x^1}
$$

Comment: I know that if $f$ has continuous second order partial derivatives then your last line would have an equal sign. However this to me (your answer) proves $f$ doesn't have continuous second order partial derivatives, I can't make the connection to why this is useful (I'm not saying it isn't useful just that I'm not smart enough to see why)

Comment: $f$ must be continuously differentiable infinitely?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential#Two_and_three_dimensions

Comment: Thanks I found that really useful